# Pubchempy Error: BadRequestError | I want to generate Pubchem Fingerprint

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
!pip install pubchempy
import pubchempy as pcp
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from google.colab import files
import time as tm

df1 = pd.read_csv('/content/Excipient_CID.csv')

cidvals = df1['CID']
componentFingerprint = []
for cid in cidvals:
  c = pcp.Compound.from_cid(cid)
  componentFingerprint.append(c.cactvs_fingerprint)
  tm.sleep(0.1)

df2 = df1.assign(fp=componentFingerprint)
i = 1
for  componentFingerprint in c.cactvs_fingerprint:
    df2['fp'] = df2['fp'].astype(str)
    df2['fp'+str (i)] = df2['fp'].str[i-1:i]
    i = i+ 1
#print(componentFingerprint)
print(df2)
```

We get following error:

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pubchempy.py in request(identifier, namespace, domain, operation, output, searchtype, **kwargs)
        270         log.debug('Request data: %s', postdata)
    --> 271         response = urlopen(apiurl, postdata)
        272         return response
    
    9 frames
    /usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
        221         opener = _opener
    --> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
        223 
    
    /usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
        530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
    --> 531             response = meth(req, response)
        532 
    
    /usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
        640             response = self.parent.error(
    --> 641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
        642 
    
    /usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
        568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
    --> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
        570 
    
    /usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
        502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
    --> 503             result = func(*args)
        504             if result is not None:
    
    /usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
        648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
    --> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
        650 
    
    HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: PUGREST.BadRequest
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    BadRequestError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-51-8bda272eda3c> in <module>()
          2 componentFingerprint = []
          3 for cid in cidvals:
    ----> 4   c = pcp.Compound.from_cid(cid)
          5   componentFingerprint.append(c.cactvs_fingerprint)
          6   tm.sleep(0.1)
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pubchempy.py in from_cid(cls, cid, **kwargs)
        724         :param int cid: The PubChem Compound Identifier (CID).
        725         """
    --> 726         record = json.loads(request(cid, **kwargs).read().decode())['PC_Compounds'][0]
        727         return cls(record)
        728 
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pubchempy.py in request(identifier, namespace, domain, operation, output, searchtype, **kwargs)
        272         return response
        273     except HTTPError as e:
    --> 274         raise PubChemHTTPError(e)
        275 
        276 
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pubchempy.py in __init__(self, e)
       1295             pass
       1296         if self.code == 400:
    -> 1297             raise BadRequestError(self.msg)
       1298         elif self.code == 404:
       1299             raise NotFoundError(self.msg)
    
    BadRequestError: 'PUGREST.BadRequest'
```

Comment: Looks like its internet issue. Make sure you have good network connectivity. Thanks!